# How to GroupBy objects from a list by some common catalog of properties in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've been struggling with a problem with one of my lists of data because one of the requirements after generating it is to group some of them by some common parameters (more than 1)

What I should get at the end is a map where the value is a list of common objects. For example.

```
List<Cause> listToGroup = new ArrayList<>();

listToGroup.add(Similar);
listToGroup.add(Common);
listToGroup.add(Similar);
listToGroup.add(Similar);
listToGroup.add(Common);
```

In a weird way to represent one group (Similar) and the other (Common), those should be separated into two different lists (that list is generated by a request to other methods, in that case, I just added manually to show what could be the contained data in the list). My main problem is the criteria to group them because is based on a group of parameters that are shared, but not all (if the required parameters are equal, should belong to the same list) In the class shown below, that behaviour is seen because there are some parameters that are not being considered.

```
public class Cause extends GeneralDomain {
     //parameters which must be equals between objects
     private Long id;
     private Date creationDate;
     private Part origin;
     private Part destination;

     //parameters which are not required to be equal
     private BigDecimal value
     private Stage stageEvent

     //omitted getters and setters
}
```

I've been seeing the comparator method and the groupingBy method provided in Java 8, but at the moment I just know how to perform that task considering just one parameter (for example grouping them by id) And I have no idea about how to group them using more than one parameter.

```
//this should be the code if the requirement would be just one parameter to groupby, but in my case are more than one.
 Map<Long, List<Cause>> result = request.getList(criteria)
.stream()
.map(p -> parsin.createDto(p))
.collect(groupingBy(Cause ::getId));
```

I would be really glad for any suggestion. If my explanation is not clear, I'm so sorry. That became so complicated that even is hard for me to explain

Comment: Create a key object taking those properties you are interested in and having equality based on them, then use e.g. `groupingBy(cause -> new Key(cause))`. Or use an ad-hoc key like `groupingBy(cause -> Arrays.asList(cause.getId(), cause.getCreationDate(), cause.getOrigin(), cause.getDestination()))`

Comment: @Holger I think your comment should be an answer :)